# How to Migrate data of size 5 to 10 TB to azure from on-premises

Tags: azure, azure-storage, large-file-upload

Which Azure service is preferred while transferring data of range 5TB to 10TB ?

I have checked Import/export , Data lake, Storage explorer

Comment: *I have checked Import/export , Data lake, Storage explorer* -> So? What was the conclusion?

Comment: Iam trying to find the best one out of security (cost) and cost out of these

Answer (score 1):

This article provides an overview of some of the common Azure data transfer solutions. The article also links out to recommended options depending on the network bandwidth in your environment and the size of the data you intend to transfer.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-choose-data-transfer-solution

Regarding the pricing you may refer to this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/storage/files/).

Kindly let us know if the above helps or you need further assistance on this issue.